# Error when adding cell delegate to class - swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Why do I get an error, when I add this code?:
`, myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate`

To my class?:

```
class myProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate {
```

This is the beginning of my `myProfileTableViewCell.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

protocol myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate {
    func watchTrainingPressed(cell: myProfileWorkoutTableViewCell)
}

class myProfileWorkoutTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
```

and this is my button inside the cell:

```
@IBAction func watchTrainingPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let _ = delegate {
            delegate?.watchTrainingPressed(self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @dan `Type 'myProfileTableViewController does not conform to protocol 'myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate'`

Comment: Does your table view controller implement the function declared in your protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the function

`func watchTrainingPressed(cell: myProfileWorkoutTableViewCell)`

inside your `myProfileTableViewController` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you add `myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate` at the top of the class `myProfileTableViewController` and all non optional functions.

```
class myProfileTableViewController:UIViewController, myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate {

     // viewDidLoad etc....

    //MARK: - myProfileWorkoutTableViewCellDelegate

    func watchTrainingPressed(cell: myProfileWorkoutTableViewCell) {

          print("code goes here")
    }
}
```

Worth pointing out also because your delegate is optional `delegate?.` you don't need the `if let _ = delegate {` check